# MultiOS data-manager

Tags: software-recommendation

Does Ubuntu have any multi-platform application which can help manage and store information? I need a data organizer type of software which can create DB's that can I open on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: There are several [cross platform](http://askubuntu.com/tags/crossplatform/info) database applications and the best application for you depends on your specific use case, so please edit your question and add that information to it.

Comment: What do you mean by data organiser? Something like MS Access? Or something more powerful (like a proper SQL database)?

Comment: Just a notepad with tree of documents and making a tables into it.

Answer (score 0):

You should setup a server (NAS, Android Box, or even a Virtual Machine on your desktop) where you install a web based plattform to store your information. It depends on what kind of information you want to store but in any case i would recommend kind of networked appliance (VM) or Server if you want to access the information from different hosts / OS

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called "LibreOffice Base".  It allows you to create and open databases on both Windows and Ubuntu...

In Windows, you download it from the Web, in Ubuntu you search for it in the software center (icon below)

[image: Software Center Icon]

Alternatively, if you're looking for a relational database **server**, "MySQL" is the way to go...

Answer (score -1):

VMware (or alternative)
I am not entirely sure what you are asking but the last line suggests you want to run windows and linux at the same time.

You will need something like VMware to run multiple operating systems at the same time on one machine.

I am not sure what you would want to create a database for to access and edit files between the two systems.

I would focus on the VMware first.

Comment: He's talking about an open-source database application that runs bith on Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: You understood that question?
Impressive.

Comment: @Karel: :D :D :D That's Rinzwind! ;-)

Comment: I've been in customer support for a very (very) long time...

Comment: Im just didnt know english very well and anyway linux at all :). Yes, I'm talked about crossplatform data organizer.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for clarifying, I would agree with Karel and Fabby's suggestion to look at "LibreOffice Base" as a starting point.
Karel is right that there are many more cross-platform open source database applications to choose from.